# View with Group By and 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to create a view that groups by the column INCM that only returns the OLDEST date and the respective 3rd column with details.

This works well with just 2 columns as the following:

```
SELECT [INCM],min(Submit_Date) as Datsubmite From [OP].[TABLEXAMPLE]

WHERE
Work_Info_Notes Like '%test%' 
  and Work_Info_Notes Like '%raised%' 
  and Work_Info_Notes Like '%with%'
  and Work_Info_Notes Like'%test2%'

Group By INCM
```

I just can't figure out how to include the 3rd column as I don't know how to specify which row is to be picked for the 3rd column. I want the 3rd column to return the respective notes of the displayed min(Submit_Date)but not sure how to approach this:

```
SELECT [INCM],min(Submit_Date) as Datsubmite, Work_Info_Notes
From [OP].[TABLEXAMPLE]

WHERE
Work_Info_Notes Like '%test%' 
  and Work_Info_Notes Like '%raised%' 
  and Work_Info_Notes Like '%with%'
  and Work_Info_Notes Like'%test2%'

Group By INCM
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Column
> 'OP.TABLEXAMPLE.Work_Info_Notes' is invalid in the select list because
> it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
> clause.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical method in SQL is to use `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT t.*   -- or whatever columns you want
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INCM ORDER BY submit_date) as seqnum
      FROM [OP].[TABLEXAMPLE] t
      WHERE Work_Info_Notes Like '%test%'  AND
            Work_Info_Notes Like '%raised%' AND
            Work_Info_Notes Like '%with%' AND
            Work_Info_Notes Like'%test2%'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't known which SQL-Server you're using, but in Oracle you would use:

```
FIRST_VALUE(Work_Info_Notes)
  OVER (PARTITION BY INCM ORDER BY Submit_Date) AS lowest_sal
```

If this is MS-SQL, take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sql-server`.
A handy `TOP(1) WITH TIES .. ORDER BY` helps

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES [INCM], Submit_Date as Datsubmite , Work_Info_Notes
From [OP].[TABLEXAMPLE]
WHERE
Work_Info_Notes Like '%test%' 
  and Work_Info_Notes Like '%raised%' 
  and Work_Info_Notes Like '%with%'
  and Work_Info_Notes Like'%test2%'    
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by [INCM] order by Submit_Date desc)
```